# How can I debug my ionic app(including cordova) in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

hi i'm making a ionic app, and it includes cordova plugin like camera-preview and geolocation.

So I want to debug my app in iphone(device) not an emulator.

I have searched about this problem, but I didn't find specific guidelines about it. This is my first time making ionic app.

Are there any pages dealing with this problem? 
Please give me some advices

Answer (score 1):

You can use Safari -> Web Inspector to debug your iOS ionic app.

Follow the below link for more details.

http://legacy.docs.ionic.io/docs/safari-inspector

Hope this helps :)